# iOS simulator lost last animation frame

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

For some time I have had an interesting iOS simulator issue - it constantly doesn't draw the last frame of any animation. For example:

- in push animation the new view doesn't go right to the end, so I see the right border of the previous view
- in dissolve animation alpha doesn't go to zero, so I still see the view with alpha near zero
- if I have a button with different normal and selected images, then first tap does nothing (in fact, it does, but doesn't show), and second tap shows previous animation, i.e. what should be done at first tap, etc.

These issues are reproduced in all simulators and apps including system ones like Calendar, Settings, etc.

I have changed a simulator scale, reinstalled the simulator, reinstalled Xcode entirely - no success.

Very strange. Not sure if this related to simulator, Xcode, or macOS. Had anybody such issue?

Comment: At the risk of posting a me too, you are not going crazy. I also have this issue, which has occurred in the last few weeks for me, on only one of my machines. Only on the simulator, not on device.

Comment: Do you happen to use NVIDIA graphic adapter?

Comment: No, I have Mac Mini 2011 with Intel HD Graphics 3000, no 3rd party drivers, Apple updates only. Is something wrong with Nvidia?

Comment: @Bms270 I'm on NVIDIA.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd an OP You need to apply a patch to your driver to solve this issue. I will post an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens with the current version of NVIDIA Web Driver (378.05.05.25f03) and requires a special patch to fix. The patch is available here:

https://github.com/mologie/NVWebDriverLibValFix/releases

Remember, this patch is unsigned and requires kernel code signing to be disabled. There are many resources online explaining how to do that depending on the type of machine you have if you are unfamiliar with the process.

This solves the slowness, lags, delays, frame loss, etc. with the iOS simulators as well as the issue with the "Profiler" in Xcode.

Comment: Ah wait, I can. Bounty coming in 24 hours (mandatory wait period).

Comment: @AirsourceLtd Thanks! Glad the answer helped you!

Comment: Patch not needed on my machine on 387.10.10.10.25.156/10.13.3.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd Where did you get that latest version?

Comment: direct from NVIDIA Driver Manager -> Check Now.